# How to use second occurrence of a data to update the first occurrence in database reading the raw data from text file C#

Tags: c#, winforms, text, split

I have a CSV data in text file as shown below. I read the text file line-by-line, split each line into an array(eg.  *strArray* ).
I want to store Equal *strArray[0]* into database as one row.

00001,07:57,010619,1,001 
00003,07:58,010619,1,001 
00002,08:30,010619,1,001 
00004,08:29,010619,1,001 
00003,20:14,010619,1,001 
00003,08:14,010619,1,001 
00001,18:02,010619,1,001 
00002,18:00,010619,1,001 
00003,18:03,010619,1,001

This is how I read the file.

```
List<Data_Obj> Data_List= new List<Data_Obj>();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dir))
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        String str;
        string[] strArray;
        str = sr.ReadLine();

        strArray = str.Split(',');
        Data_Obj obj= new Data_Obj();
        obj.card= strArray[0];
        obj.time = strArray[1];
        obj.day = Int32.Parse(strArray[2].Substring(0, 2));
        obj.mon = Int32.Parse(strArray[2].Substring(2, 2));
        obj.yr = Int32.Parse(strArray[2].Substring(4, 2));
        obj.DeviceNo = Int32.Parse(strArray[3]);
        obj.DeviceID = strArray[4];
        Data_List.Add(obj);
    }


}
```

Now the database Table should look like this

```
| Card   |EnTime |ExTime | Device| Time     |
-------------------------------------------
|00001   |07:57  | 18:02 |   1   |01/06/2019|
|00003   |07:58  | 20:14 |   1   |01/06/2018|
|00002   |08:30  | 18:00 |   1   |01/06/2018|
|00004   |08:29  |       |   1   |01/06/2018|
|00003   |08:14  | 18:03 |   1   |01/06/2018|
```

I need help as to how to do this.

Comment: What is the interface to the database?  Are you using Entity or a Connection?

Comment: If possible, use a `Dictionary<string, Data_Obj>` instead of your list. Instead of `Data_List.Add(obj)` you can then check if the dictionary `ContainsKey(strArray[0])` and change the existing data by accessing it with your key.

Comment: @jdweng I am using connection. and its Access Data base that I save the data not SQL

Comment: You are not using SQL Server, but most people still consider the Command Text a SQL Query.

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment the code should look somehow like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Data_Obj> Data_Dictionary= new Dictionary<string, Data_Obj>();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dir))
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        String str;
        string[] strArray;
        str = sr.ReadLine();

        strArray = str.Split(',');
        Data_Obj obj;
        if(!Data_Dictionary.ContainsKey(strArray[0])
        {
            obj = new Data_Obj();
            obj.card= strArray[0];
            obj.time = strArray[1];
            obj.day = Int32.Parse(strArray[2].Substring(0, 2));
            obj.mon = Int32.Parse(strArray[2].Substring(2, 2));
            obj.yr = Int32.Parse(strArray[2].Substring(4, 2));
            obj.DeviceNo = Int32.Parse(strArray[3]);
            obj.DeviceID = strArray[4];
            Data_Dictionary.Add(obj.card, obj);
        }
        else
        {
            obj = Data_Dictionary[strArray[0]];
            // Change data here
        }
    }
}
```

You only have to apply the required changes to the already existing Data_Obj...

EDIT:

I've overseen that you don't have both timestamps in your object... Maybe you can extend your Data_Obj class to have two timestamps (your EnTime and ExTime).

UPDATE:

I would recommend to you to use two DateTime objects in your class.
1st.: EnTime
2nd.: ExTime
They can replace the time,day,mon and yr properties/fields.

then you can do:

```
Dictionary<string, Data_Obj> Data_Dictionary= new Dictionary<string, Data_Obj>();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dir))
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        String str;
        string[] strArray;
        str = sr.ReadLine();

        strArray = str.Split(',');
        Data_Obj obj;
        if(!Data_Dictionary.ContainsKey(strArray[0])
        {
            obj = new Data_Obj();
            obj.card= strArray[0];
            if(int.TryParse(strArray[1].Split(':')[0], out int hour) == true) &&
               int.TryParse(strArray[1].Split(':')[1], out int minute) == true) &&
               int.TryParse(strArray[2].Substring(0, 2), out int day) == true) &&
               int.TryParse(strArray[2].Substring(2, 2), out int month) == true) &&
               int.TryParse(strArray[2].Substring(4, 2), out int year) == true)
            {
                obj.EnTime = new DateTime(year,month, day, hour, minute, 0, 0);
                obj.ExTime = DateTime.MinValue;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new FormatException("Format of dataLine must be: 00001,07:57,010619,1,001");
            }

            obj.DeviceNo = Int32.Parse(strArray[3]);
            obj.DeviceID = strArray[4];
            Data_Dictionary.Add(obj.card, obj);
        }
        else
        {
            obj = Data_Dictionary[strArray[0]];
            if(int.TryParse(strArray[1].Split(':')[0], out int hour) == true) &&
               int.TryParse(strArray[1].Split(':')[1], out int minute) == true) &&
               int.TryParse(strArray[2].Substring(0, 2), out int day) == true) &&
               int.TryParse(strArray[2].Substring(2, 2), out int month) == true) &&
               int.TryParse(strArray[2].Substring(4, 2), out int year) == true)
            {
                DateTime currentValue = new DateTime(year,month, day, hour, minute, 0, 0);
                if(obj.EnTime <= currentValue)
                {
                    if(currentValue > obj.Extime)
                    {
                        obj.ExTime = currentValue;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(obj.EnTime > obj.Extime)
                    {
                        obj.ExTime = obj.EnTime;
                    }

                    obj.EnTime = currentValue;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new FormatException("Format of dataLine must be: 00001,07:57,010619,1,001");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Be aware that you should add some checks for the split and substring operations. They migth throw an exception if the format is incorrect...

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes I included the timestamps in the object. This actually gave me a good approach to solving the problem. But since I am checking only the keys, it does not include data after the second key. eg. if key 00001 appearing 6 times in the text file it takes the 1st and the 6th only. I thought of also checking the date but I couldn't. I get error accesing  Data_Dictionary.values